# Is this the correct implementation of freeing a trie node data structure in c?

Tags: c, recursion, trie

I've been trying to implement a Trie data structure in c.  I am not good with recursive functions and I was wondering if this implementation to free the trie node and all of its children was correct.

```
int freeNode(Trienode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        //nothing to free
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++)
    {
        if(!(root -> children[i] == NULL))
        {   
            freeNode(root -> children[i]);
            free(root -> children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(root);
    //successfully freed the root node and all of its children nodes and its children...etc.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You have a "double free" Remove the `free` inside the loop. It is handled at the bottom of the recursive call

Comment: Create a program that is using this function, run it and observe if the behavior is correct. Then use Valgrind to detect possible memory leaks - this will help ensuring you are freeing all and only what needs to be freed.

Comment: Also _never_ do (eg) `foo -> bar`. Replace with `foo->bar`

Comment: And `if(!(root -> children[i] == NULL))` is easier with `if (root->children[i] != NULL)`

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `root -> children[i]` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `root->children[i]`.

Comment: The standard `free()` function doesn't return a value; I wonder why yours does.  You don't use the return value from the recursive call.